# What are the .rs files in build/classes?

Tags: java, netbeans, javac

What is the purpose of the `.rs` files sometimes found in the build/classes compiler output?

The contents seem to be the fully qualified names of all classes defined in the corresponding `.java` file.  For example:
[MainFrameApplication.rs](https://github.com/kdiverson/phyloGeoRef/blob/ac9683f6983d38cb8164898cececbb6fb9658539/phyloGeoRef/build/classes/org/forester/archaeopteryx/MainFrameApplication.rs) generated from [MainFrameApplication.java](https://github.com/kdiverson/phyloGeoRef/blob/ac9683f6983d38cb8164898cececbb6fb9658539/phyloGeoRef/src/org/forester/archaeopteryx/MainFrameApplication.java).

I'm not sure which compilers do this.  I examined documentation and source code for Oracle's javac and Eclipse's ecl, but found nothing.  I did find a [connection to NetBeans](http://google.com/search?q=netbeans%20%22rs%20files%22).

Comment: As per my view, this file is just a document.
Not look like rust language file.